# Argument of type 'File' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob' in formData

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have some upload code that takes a file from a file input field and uploads it

```
  basicUpload(files: File[]){
    var formData = new FormData();
    Array.from(files).forEach((file) => formData.append('file', file))
    this.http.post('https://file.io', formData)
      .subscribe(event => {  
        console.log('done')
      })
  }
```

This works and I can upload a file from the browser, but when I try to prepare the code for a native platform. I get this error

```
Argument of type 'File' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
  Type 'File' is not assignable to type 'Blob'
```

I assume I need to type the file on this line

```
Array.from(files).forEach(file => formData.append('file', file))
```

But i am not sure how to achieve that.

Answer (score 5):

instead of

```
var formData = new FormData();
```

use

```
const formData:any = new FormData();
```

Note: better to use const as type than var.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have import these package `import { File } from '@ionic-native/file'`
in your code you have declare data type as `files: File[]` 
here is object type mismatch you just declare it any `files: any` or just `files`

Answer (score 1):

If `File` really extended `Blob`, it wouldn't have produced the error. This may be a result of importing `Blob` from somewhere, like `import { Blob } from "buffer"` or `import { Blob } from "node:buffer"` overwriting the built-in, or the `File` name is not what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I am uploading pictures in ionic using this code. It is actually converting pictures into `base64`.

```
openCamera(isGallery: boolean) {
let options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}

const optionsGallery: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
}

this.camera.getPicture(isGallery? optionsGallery : options).then((imageData) => {
  let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  let id = 1;
  if (this.pictures.length > 0) {
   id = this.pictures[this.pictures.length - 1].id + 1;
  }
  let data = {
    id: id,
    src: base64Image,
    name: this.title
  };
  this.pictures.push(data);
}, (err) => {

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
formData.append('file', file as Blob)
```

This should work. Type 'File' extends Blob.